# Two differents button for one Animation Drawable

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with my code I develop a game on android studio and I meet the following concern.

There are two buttons on my app, a Punch button and a Kick Button and an Imageview in which I animate my images.

When I click on the punch button, I create a drawable animation of two images
when I click on the kick button, I create a drawable animation of two images as well.

The problem is that when I execute this code with two drawable animations, the application crashes !!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnPunch;
private Button btnKick;
private ImageView imageView1 ;
private ImageView imageView2 ;

private AnimationDrawable[] animationDrawable = new 
AnimationDrawable[2];

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnPunch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPunch);


imageView1 = (ImageView) 
findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

 imageView1.setBackgroundResource( 
         R.drawable.animationpunch);
animationDrawable[0] = (AnimationDrawable) 
imageView1.getBackground();

imageView2 = (ImageView) 
findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


imageView2.setBackground
Resource(R.drawable.animatio 
       nkick);
animationDrawable[1] = (AnimationDrawable) 
imageView2.getBackground();


btnPunch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
animationDrawable[1].stop();
animationDrawable[0].setOneShot(true);
animationDrawable[0].start();
}
});



btnKick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
animationDrawable[0].stop()
animationDrawable[1].setOneShot(true);
animationDrawable[1].start();
}
});

}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
//animationDrawable.start();
}
 }

</Code>
```

I yet use two different imageview for both animations
on the other hand when I remove an animation like the following code, it works well but suddenly I am limited to use the punch button, I would like it to work with both buttons

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnPunch;
private ImageView imageView1 ;

private AnimationDrawable[] animationDrawable = new 
AnimationDrawable[2];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnPunch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPunch);


imageView1 = (ImageView) 
findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


imageView1.setBackground
Resource(R.drawable.animatio 
       npunch);
animationDrawable[0] = (AnimationDrawable) 
imageView1.getBackground();


 btnPunch.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
animationDrawable[1].stop();
animationDrawable[0].setOneShot(true);
animationDrawable[0].start();
} 

}}


}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{

super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
//animationDrawable.start();
}
}
```

click on punch button, it animates my animation unch
I click on kick button, it animates my animation kick
a help?

Comment: Can you post any error messages you're getting?

Comment: The error i am getting référence me at the second line.                      
    imageView2.setBackground
    Resource(R.drawable.animatio 
       nkick);
    animationDrawable[1] = 
    (AnimationDrawable) 
    imageView2.getBackground();

Comment: Apparently i cannot use twice setbackground resource is There a way to do what i need?

Comment: Someone Can tell me what IS thé solution?